# Redirect to login page after session timeout yii

Tags: session, authentication, yii

I want to redirect my web after the session is over. I have tried this code :

```
 'user' => array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'class' => 'application.components.WebUser',
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
            'returnUrl' => array('site/index'),
            'authTimeout'=>5,
         ),
```

This code end my session but it is not redirecting to my login page. This just send me an error that tells me `Property "WebUser.username" is not defined.`. How can I redirect this to my Login page after the session is over? I'm using Yii anyway.

my webuser code

```
public function __get($name)
    {
        if($this->hasState($name))
            return $this->getState($name);
        else
            return parent::__get($name);
    }
```

Comment: How is your WebUser code?

Comment: it still a default yii WebUser. but this error keep sending to the this code(I have edit my question with webUser code)

Comment: What you posted is not a class...

Comment: but it keeps telling me that the error is in that part. Anyway I don't know where toput the redirect code and page if the session is over. do you mean this class class CWebUser extends CApplicationComponent implements IWebUser? it is at the top of my code

Comment: can anyone help this case? I'm getting pissed with this stuck. thanks